# Counting Rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I was solving a figure counting question, and boy was it hard. It gave me a rectangle, which was divided into 9 parts vertically and 6 parts horizontally. I had to get the total number of rectangles.

Since there were so many, I had immense difficulty in counting. Is there a formula for that?

Comment: Consider how many _pairs_ of horizontal lines and how many _pairs_ of vertical lines you can choose from the given set to delimit a rectangle. (That's what @RobertZ said in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2487182), just in a bit more detailed way. It is another formulation but same idea, that's why I post it as a comment, not another answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rectangle is basically a set of $2$ pairs of parallel lines.

If you have $h$ and $v$ horizontal and vertical lines, then you have $h-1$ and $v-1$ parts.

Then the total number of rectangles is the total number of combinations of horizontal lines, multiplied with the total number of combinations of vertical lines.

This is $^hC_2\cdot^vC_2$, which is equal to $${hv (h-1)(v-1)}\over4$$

In your case $h=7, v=10$, which gives $945$ rectangles. Quite a lot to count, so you are possibly expected to know the formula, or derive it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  Read Robert Z's hint.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry. Correcting.

Comment: You said, correctly, that if you have $h$ horizontal lines and $v$ vertical lines, then you have $h - 1$ horizontal parts and $v - 1$ vertical parts.  In this case, that means $h - 1 = 6  \implies h = 7$ and $v - 1 = 9 \implies v = 10$.  Your answer is too large since the order in which the  lines are selected does not matter.  As Robert Z said, we need to choose two distinct horizontal lines and two distinct vertical lines.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I did take Combinations. Order is taken in Permutations.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo According to your formula, a 1x1 rectangle (i.e. h=v=2) has 4 rectangles in it.

Comment: Finally got the problem. I took the wrong formula for $^nC_r$!

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Any rectangle is given by choosing two distinct horizontal lines and  two distinct vertical lines.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking for an answer, not a hint.

Comment: @Buddha  This is a good hint.  On the other hand, the answer you received from MalayTheDynamo is wrong.